# PHP redirect stop working after mod_rewrite (.htaccess) file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My redirect logic has stopped working ever since I've put the following code

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /site3/public/admin/filenotfound.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site3/public/admin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+)?\&picid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/picid/%3/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/picid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2&picid=$3 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?caseid=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/caseid/%2/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+?)(?:\.php)?\?search=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/search/%2/? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/caseid/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?caseid=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

## hide .php extension snippet    
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=302,L,NE]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

this is how i'm redirecting my page

```
function redirectTO($url = null){
    if($url != null){
        header("Location:{$url}");
        exit();
    }
}

redirectTO('page.php');
```

I'm not a very good of mode rewriting therefore i cannot work out where the issue is please advise me what should, by the way they work fine if remove my `.htaccess` file doesn't work if put that file back on.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use full path of your of the URL i.e. `www.example.com/page.php`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're removing `.php` extension using rewrite rules and adding a trailing slash use this PHP code to redirect:

```
function redirectTO($url = null){
    if($url != null){
        header("Location: /site3/public/admin/" . $url);
        exit();
    }
}

redirectTO('page/');
```